# Accessing files in Play dev and prod mode

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I'm having a trouble accessing some files in universal way across app run modes.
I have folder "resources" in app root folder, which contains some crucial files.
When I run in dev mode, I access them in simple manner, like:

```
Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath()+"/resources/file.file";
```

But after I package my app via dist commmand (I've modified build.sbt so that "resources" folder is copied near conf and lib folders), the code above stops working, due to this line

```
Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath()
```

now returns a path to bin folder, in which app.bat is ran from. So if in dev mode, the code above returns correct path like X:/app/resources/file.file, in prod mode it's like X:/app/bin/resources/file.file which is incorrect.

P.S. I absolutely can't put my files in conf folder and access them as a resource from a classloader because of numerous reasons which are actually not important.

So the question is simple as that: how to access these file resources in a universal manner across modes, without any hardcoding. 
TY in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method on `Application` which lets you access files in the application root.

https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/Application.html#getFile-java.lang.String-

> `default java.io.File getFile(java.lang.String relativePath)`
>
> Get a file relative to the application root path.
>
> Parameters: `relativePath` - relative path of the file to fetch
>
> Returns: a file instance - it is not guaranteed that the file exists

Since you already have the `application`, you should be able to use this method to directly access the file.